# How to have multiple site (UI) languages?

Tags: multi-language

I want my wordpress to have multiple UI languages while keeping my content, ie. posts, unchanged.

If a user, who may not be an admin, whose Accept-Language HTTP header prefers German, my site returns German interface while my posts are still in English. Or, there can be a Choose Language dropdown, which only changes the user interface.

I believe it's completely feasible as the admin panel already has Site Language option, but it just doesn't change according to user preference.

I searched multiple sites with keywords like "wordpress site language bilingual", "wordpress UI bilingual". They give me results like [Multisite Language Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/), [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/). These plugins seem to manage/translate posts.

What's the correct way to provide bilingual for interface for visitors?

Comment: What are you defining as UI? wp-admin?

Comment: UI are the parts a user interacts with that are not the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31785/how-can-i-set-up-multi-language-admin-ui

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set up multi language admin ui?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31785/how-can-i-set-up-multi-language-admin-ui)

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt Not exact duplicate because I focus on visitors while the possible duplicate focuses on admin.

Comment: You may want to look into plugins such as WPML. They support translation of everything from content to themes etc.